# The use of Cc'ed in an email

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I am tying to say that I am Cc-ing my supervisor to keep her updated on an application process. I am sending this email internally but to different department.

Does following sentence convey meaning?

> Cc'ed my supervisor to keep her in the loop.

Comment: Personally, I put: "cc: Mary Watson", where Mary Watson is the name of my supervisor, and avoid turning "cc" into a verb with past tense.

Comment: Personally I rely on the fact that my work e-mail app (Microsoft Outlook) shows if anyone has received a copy of an email using the CC feature, by listing them under the To: line at the top of each email received. The recipient of the email can see all of the CC recipients and deduce the reason for their inclusion.

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey, that is true! But I wanted to be more explicit about it as I have seen some emails circling around with a short sentence indicating why X is in this email.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Personally, I prefer "cc'd" over "cc'ed", but [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/cc-ed#:%7E:text=verb%20(used%20with%20object)%2C,each%20of%20the%20department%20heads.) says both forms are acceptable.